# Deep Learning VM docker registry

Tags: google-dl-platform

May I know is the Google Deep Learning VM docker image can be downloaded to run on developer machine that has Nvidia GPU? Can it be run on other Cloud instead of Google Compute Engine? Does anyone know what is the link to the image registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May I know is the Google Deep Learning VM docker image can be downloaded to run on developer machine that has Nvidia GPU?

We have recently created environments that are fully consistent with Google Deep Learning VMs. These environments should be used whenever VMs cannot be used (local development is a nice example). They are currently in Beta and many things still need polishing but it would be nice to get your earlier feedback. List of containers:

- gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cpu:latest
- gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cu100:latest
- gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-cpu.1-0:latest (Jupyter UI is not yet functional on this one)
- gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-gpu.1-0:latest (Jupyter UI is not yet functional on this one)
- gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf-cpu.1-13:latest
- gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/tf-gpu.1-13:latest

(keep in mind that even naming might change in the future)

You can list out all the available containers with:

```sh
gcloud container images list --repository="gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release"
```

Here is how you can start locally:

### CPU Env

```sh
IMAGE_NAME="gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base.cpu:m23"

docker pull "${IMAGE_NAME}"
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080/tcp -v "${HOME}:/home" "${IMAGE_NAME}"
```

### GPU Env

- Install Nvidia drivers required by the env (TODO)
- Install Nvidia-docker

```sh
IMAGE_NAME="gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base.cu100:m23"

docker pull "${IMAGE_NAME}"
docker run --runtime=nvidia -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080/tcp -v "${HOME}:/home" "${IMAGE_NAME}"
```

> Can it be run on other Cloud instead of Google Compute Engine?

VM images - no. Containers, in theory, yes but we can not guarantee that it will work.

> Does anyone know what is the link to the image registry?

For VM images there is no such concept as image registry, however, for containers, you can use links that I have pasted at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Are the Dockerfiles for the VM docker images made public anywhere? GCP documentation gives a general overview: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-containers/docs/overview, but it's hard to create derivative containers without specifics. See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027201/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-the-google-cloud-platform-deep-learning-vm

Comment: Is it possible to use a custom docker image to run on the Deep Learning Platform?